# Vimeo API: how to create/export a clip contained in an uploaded video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Any API call to create / export / download a defined segment of a video uploaded to Vimeo Professional account?

Stated alternatively: create a clip from an uploaded video, possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but it's only possible to download whole video files from Vimeo; any cutting or editing to view only specific parts of a video will have to be done on the user's end.